# Solr difficulty getting fuzzy search with multiple terms

Tags: solr, sunspot

Suppose someone's name is Alessia Keeling.  I'm having difficulty getting the following queries to work

`q=Alessia Keeling` returns a result

`q=Alessia` returns a result

`q=Alessia Keel` returns a result

however,

`q=Alessia Keeli` and `q=Alessia Keelin` returns no results

I've tried quite a few things here in my schema.xml file, but I don't have much METHOD to my MADNESS.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="20" side="front"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Solr Admin Analyzer shows that it will match both "Alessia" and various forms of "Keeling", but Sunspot is still returning no results.

**Edit 1**

Here is console testing

```
(byebug) Sunspot.commit 
(byebug) Sunspot.index
(byebug) User.search {|q| q.fulltext "Alessia Keeling" }.hits 
[#<Sunspot::Search::Hit:User 4>]  
(byebug) User.search {|q| q.fulltext "Alessia Keelin" }.hits 
[]
```

**Edit 2**
I was finally able to get somewhere.  I looked in some of my log files and noticed that the call my app was making to solr was using the query string

`"http://localhost:8981/solr/select?fq=type%3AUser&q=Eli+Donnelly+I&fl=%2A+score&qf=email+first_name_text+last_name_text+username_text+name_text+description_text&defType=dismax&start=0&rows=30&debugQuery=true`

This printed out some useful information, most useful being "parsedQuery"  I was able to see that another field was conflicting.  I have another field that handles emails and in this latter case where my query string was "Eli Donnely I", the sole letter token "I" was breaking the query because of the email field.  Adding a length filter fixed it.

Comment: Would EdgeNGramFilter be better suited for indexing, instead of querying?

Comment: This still didn't work.  I have a screenshot of the solr analysis [here](http://i.imgur.com/Y7r2R8g.png).

Comment: That screenshot indicates that it's a hit, have you reindexed after changing the schema?

Comment: hmm, yea i believe I am, I'm calling Sunspot.commit and Sunspot.index after creating the user

Comment: I'm not familar with Sunspot, but I'd think that commit should be after index?

Comment: unfortunately, I tried both ways.  Additionaly proof is that I tried the following which yielded hits:  Alessia, Alessia Keel, Alessia Kee, Alessia ee, Alessia Keeing, Alessia Keeling.  Note, I was careful to not make typos here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this from the Solr side with an example core, and the match is returned with the NGram filter while indexing. You might want to check the server side logs to see that you're actually reindexing, at least.

The field definition is as follows:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="20" side="front"/>
  </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

data.json:

```
[{"id": 1, "text": "Alessia Keeling"}, {"id": 2, "text": "Alessia Fubar"}]
```

Populate it with data:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update\?commit\=true --data-binary @data.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

Searching:

```
GET http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select\?q\=alessia%20keelin\&q.op\=AND 
[..]
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0"><doc><int name="id">1</int><str name="text">Alessia Keeling</str><long name="_version_">1473248002863792128</long></doc>  </result>
```

.. which returns the promised document, while keeping the non-matching document out of the result.

Comment: awesome thanks for the input, i'll give this a try as soon as I can and approve your answer or comment otherwise

Comment: i'm having trouble getting that data into the index with that curl command

Comment: Yes, that's complaining about expecting XML, while you're sending JSON. You'll want to add a Content-Type: application/json header, or if possible, select JSON somewhere in the interface to say that you're sending JSON. I'm not familiar with that interface, so you'll have to poke around a bit yourself @futbolpal

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you need to switch the EdgeNGramFilterFactory to the index instead of the query.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this has apparently worked. Edit the file schema.xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema name="sunspot" version="1.0">
... (other stuff)
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND|OR"/>
... (other stuff)
</schema>
```

Before, I have the defaultOperator only configured as **AND**, after I changed it, searches were getting more flexible.

Also, I'd suggest giving a look at [this page](http://code.digimonkey.com/2010/10/how-to-get-fuzzy-and-plural-matches-from-sunspot-solr/).